# I want to create a drag and drop application in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, drag-and-drop

I have posted a GIF that's states my problem.
I want to place any draggable at any dragTarget.
I don't know how to do it. I know the problem lying in this code. This was simply done while experimenting i don't know how to fix this. Please Help.

[Here is the gif for refrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSRAi.gif)

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: Yes i have tried many things like making a list of widgets that has to made when the draggable is dropped. And change the list number in onAccept function of DragTarget on comparing it with data parameters from the draggable object. I don't know the correct way to handle this iam just experimenting with the function parameters. Iam new to flutter. All i want is to whatever dropped inside that droptarget shows. I can only manage 1. If i drop the other objects it still shows the first one only.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hszt6jk0/

Comment: I dry ran your code and this is my speculation. Each of your `onDragCompleted()` is changing both `x` and `y` values on each update. First one should only update `x` and the second one should only update `y`. Thus for first one remove the line `y=1;` and for the second one remove the line `x = 2;`. But now you won't be able to place them in any other order. This is due to the limitation that you are using primitive variables and not any list or an object. So, instead of `x` and `y` use a list to keep track of which `DragTarget` holds which one of the `Draggable`s.

Comment: Yes thankyou for the help. I have removed the concept of changing variable in onDragComplete and instead used data parameters to compare and get the x value in onAccept of my dragTarget